# How is such a (delay?) equation called?

Tags: functional-equations

$ f(x) + f(x + a) = c$

where $a$ and $c$ are known constants and $f$ is the function of interest.

I understand that if one of the two terms on the LHS involved a derivative, then we would face a delayed differential equation ... but being short of a derivative, I don't even know how to call it (yet alone solve for it).

Comment: You could call it a functional equation.

Comment: More particularly, a first-order constant-coefficient linear nonhomogeneous difference equation.

Comment: Thank you, why not put this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As requested, made into an answer]

You could call it a [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation).  More particularly, a first-order constant-coefficient linear nonhomogeneous difference equation.